# How to install S6 in redhat ubi9/ubi-minimal using microdnf

Tags: dockerfile, redhat, yum, s6

For registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi-minimal9 this image, I need S6 util to be installed. Since ubi9 doesn't come with yum package manager available in the image but we have microdnf.

microdnf install s6 says there is no S6 package

Comment: What should be `S6`?